# Retrieve words from dictionary when they meet letter requirements

Tags: performance, php, strings, array, regex

I have a set of functions that retrieve words from some arbitrary dictionary based on what letters they have. For example, this function gets words that use **only** the specified letters:

```
function getWordsWithOnlySpecifiedLetters(array $dictionary, string $letters)
{
    foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value) {
        if(mb_strlen($value) > mb_strlen($letters)) unset($dictionary[$key]);
    }

    $step = 0;
    $strSplit = preg_split('//u', $letters, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($dictionary as $word) {
        $step++;
        $wordSplit = preg_split('//u', $word, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        sort($wordSplit);
        sort($strSplit);
        if (array_map('mb_strtolower', $wordSplit) === array_map('mb_strtolower', $strSplit)) {
            //echo "All specified letters from $letters are in $word | Step $step<hr>" . PHP_EOL;
            $result[] = $word;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$dictionary = ['apple', 'sample', 'api', 'pia', 'тоҷик'];
getWordsWithOnlySpecifiedLetters($dictionary, "aip");
```

This would return the words `api` and `pia`.

```
getWordsWithOnlySpecifiedLetters($dictionary, "leamps");
```

This one would return the word `sample`.

---

I also have a function that doesn't require that they exclusively use the selected letters, but rather that they use all of the specified letters (and any other letters).

```
function getWordsWithSpecifiedLetters(array $dictionary, string $letters)
{
    $step = 0;
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    $result = [];
    foreach ($dictionary as $word) {
        $step++;
        $wordSplit = preg_split('//u', $word, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $strSplit = preg_split('//u', $letters, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $wordSplit = array_filter($wordSplit, function($x) use (&$strSplit) {
            if (in_array(strtolower($x), array_map('strtolower', $strSplit), true)) {
                $pos = array_search(strtolower($x), array_map('strtolower', $strSplit), true);
                unset($strSplit[$pos]);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        if (count(array_diff($strSplit,$wordSplit)) === 0) {
            //echo "$word contains all letters of $letters | Step $step<hr>" . PHP_EOL;
            $result[] = $word;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$dictionary = ['apple', 'sample', 'api', 'pia', 'тоҷик'];
getWordsWithSpecifiedLetters($dictionary, "ple");
```

This returns the words `sample` and `apple`.

I have more **90000** words in my dictionary (UTF-8). This results in a very slow program; if I'm trying to find something from the full dictionary it may take tens of thousands of loops. How can I improve the performance of these functions?

**You can download my dictionary from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1siks3Q22kber-Lkxa5SJvSNYGMbjwV8k) and testing your code using dictionary words.**

Comment: Is your dictionary always the same? Are you planning to use multiple getWordsWithSpecifiedLetters calls with that dictionary?

Comment: Yes! I use dynamic list of words from database. Words will by updated every day. I use SQLite for db. Now I have more 90000 words in db. @juvian

Comment: You can preprocess your dictionary by having each word and the word unique letters sorted in a string. Then you sort your dictionary by these new unique letter words. For getWordsWithOnlySpecifiedLetters query, you can sort the letters from input and then do a binary search on your dictionary. You can obtain result for this query in O(log n + k) being k the amount of words that fit the criteria

Comment: How can be realized it? With PHP or in SQL? Can you show with example code? @juvian

Comment: Sorry I dont know php, can write pseudocode at best

Comment: Please write pseudocode and your algorim. Then I will show to PHP experts it for coding in StackOverflow

Comment: I still think a linear search should be fast enough, how long does php take to do a loop of 90000 elements?

Comment: In 10-20 sec will be loop

Comment: Why you think linear searching better? @juvian

Comment: I have just checked and a 1 to 90000 loop takes 2 milliseconds...

Answer (score 4):

How about removing the dictionary preparation each time at a cost of increasing your dictionary width?

You could have an alphabetized `lookup` column (the rows aren't alphabetized -- each letter of each word is sorted alphabetically) and a `word` column:

```
lookup  |  word
-----------------
aelpp   |  apple
aelmps  |  sample
aip     |  api
aip     |  pia
икотҷ   |  тоҷик
```

Using your lowercase, alphabetized `$needle`, when you want to find "whole" matches, you merely search the `lookup` column with the `=` operator.

```
SELECT `word` FROM `dictionary` WHERE `lookup` = 'икотҷ'
```

When you want to match the `$needle` characters at a minimum, you call:

```
SELECT `word` FROM `dictionary` WHERE `lookup` REGEXP '.*и.*к.*о.*т.*ҷ.*'
```

Leveraging something like this technique: [Custom REGEXP Function to be used in a SQLITE SELECT Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032951/2943403) with this intended usage: `~.*и.*к.*о.*т.*ҷ.*~u`

This, of course, is just a theoretical suggestion -- I haven't tried to do anything like this before.

And definitely remember to sanitize and escape the `$needle` to be offered to the query for security reasons.

Mostly I am suggesting that you sacrifice memory for speed.  Only the `$needle` should be modified with character sorting and strtolower actions.  These processes are expected to be "already done" on words prior to being stored in the dictionary.

Here is another post of mine with the same basic logic: [How to best compare these two strings for values even though they are in random order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49951887/2943403)

---

If altering the dictionary table structure is unattractive, this is how I would recommend searching for exact character matches in any order:

Code:

```
function getWordsContainingTheExactSpecifedLetters_inanyorder_nomore_noless(array $dictionary, string $letters, string $encoding = 'UTF-8'){
    $lettersLength = mb_strlen($letters, $encoding);  // call just once and cache
    $lettersSplit = preg_split('//u', mb_strtolower($letters, $encoding), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    sort($lettersSplit);

    $result = [];
    foreach ($dictionary as $word) {
      if(mb_strlen($word, $encoding) == $lettersLength) {
        $wordSplit = preg_split('//u', mb_strtolower($word, $encoding), null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        sort($wordSplit);
        if ($wordSplit === $lettersSplit) {
          $result[] = $word;
        }
      }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Of course, you will need to change the qualifying condition if you wish to retain larger words that merely contain the letters.

Comment: According to your algorithm, the size of the database is doubled, but the speed of searching for words is increasing @mickmackusa

Comment: That is the sacrifice that I am proposing, yes.  Whether it is "doubling"   depends on if you have other columns (beyond `word`) in the table.  Another way to express it would be to say, "at a cost of one more column".  This means doing some "heavy lifting" just once and permanently storing that data in a new column.  This _should_ allow your individual searches to be conducted with more speed.

Comment: @Otabek Did you try my suggestion?  I'm curious how much performance improved.  Or is the idea of an expanded, purpose-built table unappealing for you?

Comment: Honestly, I have not tried your offer yet. Of course, I'll practice your proposal and test the speed of the search and then tell you about the result. But still such a big load to the computer's memory is not suitable for me. Do you know of other search options with minimal load to the computer's memory? @mickmackusa

Comment: What do you think about Juvian's pseudo-code? @mickmackusa

Comment: While juvian's pseudo code _may_ be logical / well-intended, I personally find it to be less useful than cFreed's advice -- especially if you are disinterested in modifying your dictionary table structure.  Your project DOES require multibyte support and you are currently running a loop containing several multibyte functions and regex on a high volume of words.  The workload is again multiplied when factoring necessary processing of each character in each word. I think cFreed should be using `mb_strtolower()` before splitting to avoid calling the function _[character count]_ times.

Comment: All that said, my overarching advice - because performance is the priority - is to bake all of the bread before you open the bakery to customers, then you only have one job to do.

Comment: Rewrite your version of the function similar to cFreed's, correcting it. I want to look at your version of the function and I want to understand you to the maximum. @mickmackusa

Comment: Now I have all the words in the database multibyte. What if I convert them to Latin letters? Or it can convert letters in words to numbers, of course if possible. @mickmackusa

Comment: New code snippet provided.  I'm not sure that I support translating to Latin; it seems like just another level of complexity to unravel before displaying to the end user.  But, hey, it's worth the experiment -- if it turns out to be the best option for your project, then you can post it here for the benefit of others.

Comment: One more note: `array_diff()` will consume/ignore duplicate letters.  I don't know if input can be `apple` or minimized to `aple`.  Just be careful regarding duplicate letters in the haystack words and needle word.

Comment: I did not propose to modify dictionary table structure though. Its just inefficient to operate on the dictionary for each query instead of just on initialization and keep it in memory for further requests

Comment: Using a relational database, you can also store all ordered set of letters in a separate table and use a foreign key to link it with the word table. I think it can be interesting: with 90000 words, there's a good chance many of them have the same "signature".

Answer (score 2):

Your first function can be easily improved by two ways.

**Avoid changing the contents of `$dictionary`.**

```
foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value) {
    if(mb_strlen($value) > mb_strlen($letters)) unset($dictionary[$key]);
}
```

can be suppressed, simply inserting this test at the begin of the next `foreach()`:

```
if(mb_strlen($word) <= mb_strlen($letters))
```

**Don't repeat `$letters` processing.**

Currently you're sorting `$strSplit` at each `foreach()` step, while it can be done once for all before entering loop.
Likewise for `array_map('mb_strtolower', $strSplit)`.

**(also drop useless code)**

It appears that `$step` was used only for tests purpose, so you can give up.

## Finally

Taking advantage of the above recommendations, the following modified script should take less time to execute:

```
function getWordsWithOnlySpecifedLetters(array $dictionary, string $letters)
{
    $strSplit = preg_split('//u', $letters, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $strSplitLower = array_map('mb_strtolower', $strSplit);
    sort($strSplitLower);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($dictionary as $word) {
      if(mb_strlen($word) <= mb_strlen($letters)) {
        $wordSplit = preg_split('//u', $word, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        sort($wordSplit);
        if (array_map('mb_strtolower', $wordSplit) === $strSplitLower) {
          $result[] = $word;
        }
      }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

From this you might derive some improvements for your second function.

Comment: You tested your edit function code? @cFreed

Comment: This part of code return false: `if (array_map('mb_strtolower', $wordSplit) === $strSplitLower)`

Comment: @Otabek Yes, I tested, using your `aip` sample. And it works for me.

Comment: Please show me real example in [https://3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org). For me it not work now. I use php 7.1

Comment: @Otabek https://3v4l.org/tBnY6.

Comment: I found error. Now I replace `aip` to `api` in the input letters on arg of function and function not return results. Why? Old my function return results for input `api` also.

Comment: @Otabek Found! When modifying your code, I kept `sort($strSplit)`, while it must be `sort($strSplitLower)`. Edited my answer. Now it works with your `api` sample.

Comment: I tested functions old and new. Old: 3 sec, New: 1.5 sec found words from 90000 words. Second function can be performed or not? @cFreed

Comment: @Otabek As mentioned at the end of my answer, you can easily report part of these improvements to the second function. In the other hand, since it appears that it really responded to your need, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume all your words only have a-z characters. With that, an efficient check can be made by preprocessing your dictionary:

Pseudocode:

1) Preprocessing:

```
 words = dictionary
 letters = ['a'..'z']
 wordDataList = []

 for each word in words:
     wordData = new wordData()
     wordData.word = word;
     wordData.num = process(word)
     wordDataList.add(wordData)

 function process(word):
     num = 0
     for idx = 0 to letters.size():
        if letters[idx] in word:
            num = num + (1 << idx)
     return num
```

2) Queries:

```
function query(letters, allowOtherLetters):
    matching = []
    num = process(letters)
    for wordData in wordDataList:
        if (allowOtherLetters == false and wordData.num == num):
            matching.add(wordData.word)
        else if (allowOtherLetters and (wordData.num & num) == num):
            matching.add(wordData.word)

    return matching
```

Comment: This code in python? @juvian

Comment: This code can't found word with utf-8 letters? I have not words with (a-z ) letters in my dictionary. My words in cyrillic letters. @juvian

Comment: @Otabek its pseudocode, not in any language. This would work for any letters, but only 32 of them. It would be easy to extend to more letters though